# добавление в mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

есть форма с чекбоксами

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" checked name="newsletter[]" id="checkbox_{$id}" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter[]" id="checkbox_{$id}" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter[]" id="checkbox_{$id}" value="6">
</form>
```

как обработать таблицу, если например поставили галки  и нажали сохранить то я могу добавить

```
foreach ($_POST['newsletter'] as $news){
  echo $news;
}
```

а как быть, если мы галку убрали и нажали сохранить, то запись нужно удалить из таблицы
в голову пришло только удалить все записи и добавить новые

```
if ($_POST['newsletter']) {
    $modx->query("delete from `modx_goodnews_group_members` where member_id=".$modx->user->get('id')."");
    foreach ($_POST['newsletter'] as $news){
        $q = $modx->prepare("INSERT INTO `modx_goodnews_group_members` (`goodnewsgroup_id`, `member_id`) VALUES (".$news.", ".$modx->user->get('id').")");
        $q->execute();
        if ($modx->lastInsertId()){
            echo "sdf";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `delete ... where member_id=? and goodnewsgroup_id not in(?,?,?)` Список для передачи в not in подготовить во время цикла с insert

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не удалять все, а использовать флаг `DISABLED`

```
if ($_POST['newsletter']) {
  $modx->query(
    "UPDATE `modx_goodnews_group_members` SET disabled = 1 where member_id=".$modx->user->get('id')
  );
  foreach ($_POST['newsletter'] as $news){
    $q = $modx->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO `modx_goodnews_group_members` (`goodnewsgroup_id`, `member_id`) VALUES (".$news.", ".$modx->user->get('id').") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), disabled = NULL"
    );
    $q->execute();
    if ($modx->lastInsertId()){
        echo "sdf";
    }
  }
  $modx->query(
    "delete from `modx_goodnews_group_members` where member_id=".$modx->user->get('id')." AND disabled IS NOT NULL"
  );
}
```

Еще лучше - работать через параметры

```
if ($_POST['newsletter']) {
  $update = $modx->prepare(
    "UPDATE `modx_goodnews_group_members` SET disabled = 1 where member_id= ?"
  );
  $update->execute($modx->user->get('id'));
  $insert = $modx->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `modx_goodnews_group_members` (`goodnewsgroup_id`, `member_id`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), disabled = NULL"
  );
  foreach ($_POST['newsletter'] as $news) {
    $insert->query($news, $modx->user->get('id'));
    if ($modx->lastInsertId()){
      echo "sdf";
    }
  }
  $delete = $modx->prepare(
    "delete from `modx_goodnews_group_members` where member_id= ? AND disabled IS NOT NULL"
  );
  $delete->execute($modx->user->get('id'));
}
```